# Power BI Table Column not working correctly

Tags: powerbi

I have the following DAX query that calculates the difference between TokenMinutes and BaselineUsage.  It works. See image below.

However, when viewing the output in Table format, the Excess Total is incorrect.  Any ideas why? BTW... when I export the data and open in Excel, the column sum is correct.  It appears that only in Power BI does the total not match up.

```
ExcessUsage = 
    IF
    (
        (MAX(Vtatistics[TokenMinutes]) - (Reporting[Ad-HocUsage] + Reporting[BaselineUsage]) < 0),
        (CALCULATE
            (
                MAX(Statistics[TokenMinutes]) - (Reporting[Ad-HocUsage] + Reporting[BaselineUsage])
            )*-1),
    BLANK()
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... here is the solution.

```
EU = 
    SUMX(SUMMARIZE(VALUES(CosmosReporting),CosmosReporting[JobEndTime]),
[MinutesUsed] - [Base Usage])
```